# Как правильно отнять время?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, время, timezone

Есть код, который отнимает время до определенного дня, на локальном компьютере с таймзоной `Europe/Moscow` все правильно работает, на сервере локаль другая, поэтому и время другое, что вполне логично. Но даже с указанием таймзоны получаю неверный результат, почему?

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

day = datetime(2023, 5, 7).astimezone(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))
now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))
print(day-now)
```

Comment: Метод astimezone преобразует время из текущего часового пояса в указанное. Когда вы находитесь в Москве, этот метод ничего не делает, а в других часовых поясах astimezone отмотает время вперёд или назад относительно текущего пояса

Comment: @andreymal хм, а как правильно тогда будет отнять время? Не хотелось бы через `timedelta` в тупую прибавлять недостающие часы

Comment: Например методом [localize](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) назначить часовой пояс без перемотки

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, помогло, можете как ответ оформить